# UserProfile Registration erases all rows

Tags: django, registration

I have created a user registration view and this is it:

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.POST.copy() # so we can manipulate data  
    # random username
    data['username'] = hashlib.md5( data['email'] ).hexdigest()
    data['username'] = data['username'][0:30]
    #data['username'] = ''.join([choice(letters) for i in xrange(30)])
    form = RegisterForm(data)   
    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save()
        #UserProfile.objects.create(user=new_user)
        return HttpResponse("Thanks for Registering")       
else:
    form = RegisterForm()

return render_to_response("CTUser/register.html", { 'form': form, })
```

When I uncommented the UserProfile line:

```
#UserProfile.objects.create(user=new_user)
```

the email and password are saved correctly, but when It is there, all the info is erased. Am I doing something wrong here?

here is the UserProfile classs:

```
class UserProfile(User):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
#user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

#profile sub URL
pagelink = models.CharField(max_length=40)

#one or many albums
albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album)
```

UPDATE(10/19/11):
Here is the registration form function:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):   
email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email Address", max_length=75)  

class Meta:
    model = User
    #exclude = ['username',]
    fields = ("username", "email")  

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        raise forms.ValidationError("This email address already exists. Did you forget your password?")
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return email

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    user.is_active = True # change to false if using email activation
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if new_user contains all data you want to save. Paste RegisterForm code.

EDIT

try to change:

```
user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
```

into

```
user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
```

Comment: I will tonight, but new_user has all the values. the e-mail / an MD5 hashed version of the e-mail for the username field, and the password field. I've check it in the admin page when registering without creating the UserProfile.objects.create(user=new_user) object.